# Where to know exactly about the differences between symfony v1 and v2 changes?

Tags: symfony, symfony1, symfony-2.3

I am learning symfony v2 but since the site which I am going to be working on is created in symfony v1 so where to know exactly the differences between v1 and v2 since I am not getting anything which would clear the differences between v1 and v2 and clearly I saw that in both versions there is alot more difference than just directories difference...for instance I do know that routing is present in both but routing handling is different in both also I am not sure if Doctrine is available also I don't know that where would I find the Controllers and Entity etc???? and also where to get templates also I don't see any twig in v1 so if anyone can please help me out?? Also that where are Bundles available in symfony v1 as in v2 it's normally should be present in src folder..!???

Specifically V1.2.12 and V1.4 details in comparison with V2.8???

Comment: Unfortunately the only way is to read the documentation for both because are two completely different frameworks.

Comment: @gp_sflover : The problem is that I am not getting any best working documentation for v1 but v2 has lots of good documentation..! Also how to check that which version changes what things as I am sure that even versions have differences which needs to be learned too..!

Comment: Hi, have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/introduction/symfony1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site you are going to be working on is Symfony v1, you are wasting your time reading the docs on v2.

There is no resemblance whatsoever, no overlapping documentation - they are literally two separate frameworks.

Here is excellent documentation for [learning Symfony v1.x](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Umair Shah Yousafzai,

As I'am currently working on symfony v1, Let me share what I know

1) **Routing** :
`Path : apps/frontend/config/routing.yml`
Usage :

`homepage:
  url:   /index
  param: { module: Dashboard, action: index }`

Module here refers to the Bundle in symfony v2 or higher.
[Reference](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/05?orm=Doctrine)

2) **Controller** :
`Path : apps/frontend/Dashboard/actions/actions.class.php`
Usage: 
 In symfony v1,
    `public function executeIndex() {
        //your code here
    }`

In symfony v2,
    `public function indexAction() {
        //your code here
    }`

[Reference](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/04?rm=Propel)

In symfony v2 or higher we use something called "indexAction" but in symfony v1, we give a prefix "executeIndex".

3) **View** :
`Path : apps/frontend/Dashboard/templates/indexSuccess.php`
[Reference](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer)

4) **DB** 
Let me create an entity file for User table.
`Path : config/schema.xml` 
The schema.yml file contains the description of all tables and their 
       columns
[Reference](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/03?orm=Propel)

Path :
    `lib/model/map/UserMapBuilder.php
    lib/model/om/BaseUser.php
    lib/model/User.php and UserPeer.php`

Here UserPeer.php has all the custom functions related to the entity.

I hope this will help you to start on.

Thanks,